# Ruby on Rails: BlueCloth gem cannot work in production when deployed to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, markdown, bluecloth

I'm trying to use the `BlueCloth` gem in order to parse some markdown for my rails app. I added it to my gem file:

```
    gem 'BlueCloth'
```

In my `.html.erb` views I user the code

```
    <%=  BlueCloth.new(post.content).to_html.html_safe %>
```

To render the markdown as html. This works completely fine in my local dev environment, but when I push to heroku, even after running `bundle install` and restarting the app, accessing the app generates internal server errors.

I get the following error in the logs:

```
    ActionView::Template::Error (uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::BlueCloth):
```

I include `BlueCloth` in the gem file:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.8'

gem 'pg'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'devise'
gem 'BlueCloth'
```

I have also run the command `bundle install` via the heroku command line.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you know for sure that the BlueCloth gem is available on your Heroku location... even after running Bundler?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean, but this works in the console after I type `require 'bluecloth'` so I think so?

Comment: How can I check that the gem is available on the Heroku location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that I was using the old version of the `BlueCloth` gem.

The old gem is called `BlueCloth` and the new one is called `bluecloth`

Changing the line in my gem file:

```
    gem 'BlueCloth'
```

To:

```
    gem `bluecloth`
```

Fixed it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your manually requiring files. It might be easier for you if you use `bundler` to `require` everything for you and then you dont have to add `require` to any other `.rb` file. Its very simple to do this. Depending on your Rails version, here are two links that should help you out:

[Rails 2.3](http://gembundler.com/v1.3/rails23.html)

[Rails 3](http://gembundler.com/v1.3/rails3.html)

Comment: Unfortunately that is not the case. I already use bundler, and I have added my gem file in the original post.

Comment: @PaulBenigeri Above your ApplicationController try and put require 'bluecloth' and in your Gemfile change it to lower case, this happened to me once, see if it makes a difference, if not then we can move on to other possible issues.